# Extract the Urls in below data

Tags: javascript

How to extract urls in javascript from below data? Can you write code for me please.

```
[
Image{url:'/images/HH/Images/US/NYC/NYC-MEL-1.jpg', description='Exterior', 
          alt='null', sortOrder=1, externalUrl='null'}, 
Image{url='/images/HH/Images/US/NYC/NYC-MEL-9.jpg', description='Exterior', 
          alt='null', sortOrder=1, externalUrl='null'}, 
Image{url='/images/HH/Images/US/NYC/NYC-MEL-11.jpg', description='Lobby', 
          alt='null', sortOrder=4, externalUrl='null'}, 
Image{url='/images/HH/Images/US/NYC/NYC-MEL-5.jpg', description='Guest Room', 
          alt='null', sortOrder=34, externalUrl='null'}, 
Image{url='/images/HH/Images/US/NYC/NYC-MEL-6.jpg', description='Guest Room', 
          alt='null', sortOrder=34, externalUrl='null'}, 
Image{url='/images/HH/Images/US/NYC/NYC-MEL-7.jpg', description='Guest Room', 
          alt='null', sortOrder=34, externalUrl='null'}, 
Image{url='/images/HH/Images/US/NYC/NYC-MEL-8.jpg', description='Guest Room', 
          alt='null', sortOrder=34, externalUrl='null'}, 
Image{url='/images/HH/Images/US/NYC/NYC-MEL-10.jpg', description='Guest Room', 
          alt='null', sortOrder=34, externalUrl='null'},
Image{url='/images/HH/Images/US/NYC/NYC-MEL-3.jpg', description='Guest Room', 
          alt='null', sortOrder=34, externalUrl='null'}, 
Image{url='/images/HH/Images/US/NYC/NYC-MEL-2.jpg', description='Guest Room', 
          alt='null', sortOrder=34, externalUrl='null'}, 
Image{url='/images/HH/Images/US/NYC/NYC-MEL-4.jpg', description='Guest Room', 
          alt='null', sortOrder=34, externalUrl='null'}
]
```

Comment: this isn't how stack overflow works - write the code yourself and comeback if you have a specific problem

Comment: Nobody is going to do that work  for you. Do it ur self. If you then face problems, we will try to help you out .

Comment: your post is doing nothing but distracting

Comment: What type of data is that? If it's JSON, the syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I'll just give you a simple idea, but no code: use the "split" method, i.e:

```
var myStr = "Hello, I'm here!"; 
var splitedString = myStr.split(", ");
```

The result in `splitedString` is an array like this `["Hello","I'm here!"]`.

Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, its not gonna be so plain vanilla like this. The op here will have to travel line by line . Then he will have to split based upon multiple delimiters like: ":" , "=", that too only after he finds a string called : url.

Comment: Yes you're right, but if the data is not formatted, you need to handle it as a simple string.